# Assigning a category to a product via has_many :through

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What's the best way to allow a user to assign a category to a product s/he creates?  Right now I have the Product and Category models connected through an intermediary Categorization model.

**product.rb**

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :name

  has_many :categorizations
  has_many :categories, :through => :categorizations
end
```

**category.rb**

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name

  has_many :categorizations
  has_many :products, :through => :categorizations
end
```

**categorization.rb**

```
class Categorization < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :category_id, :product_id  # Should I leave these accessible?

  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :category
end
```

I'm ultimately trying to get it to work in the terminal as:

```
> product = Product.create(name: "Product A", description: "Product A description")
> Category.create(name: "Cat A")
> product.categories
> []
> product.categories = "Cat A"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a category with a name "Cat A", but then you are assigning a string "Cat A" to product.categories

Try this:

```
product.categories.create(:name => "Cat A")
```